# Promise catch not being caught in test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, promise, karma-jasmine

I have some code that looks like:

```
function foo(){
  bar().catch(function(){
    //do stuff
  }
}

function bar(){
  return promiseReturner().then(
    function(result){
      if(_.isEmpty(result)){
        throw "Result is empty";
      }
    }
  )
}
```

I'm trying to test that the `//do stuff` block is called when `result` is empty:

```
deferred.resolve(null);
foo();
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Now this does actually trigger the `throw` block, but for some reason that `throw` block is not being caught by the `catch` function. Whats more interesting is that when this same code runs outside of the test environment, it behaves as expected.

Why am I unable to trigger the catch block in my test code?

Comment: What promise implementation are you using? How exactly do you confirm whether the `do stuff` runs or not? Why doesn't `foo` return a promise, and where does the test wait for it?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using Angular's `$q`. The `do stuff` block has behavior that I can test for, so I can tell if it has run. The `foo` function doesn't return a promise because its meant to be a terminal code block for the promises - so no more are needed after it. The test assumes that after the `$apply()` everything has run and the expectations can begin.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which kind of promise implementation you are using and the context but maybe you can just try to add a return statement to the foo function

```
function foo(){
  return bar().catch(function(){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```